# How to change android app icon dynamically?

Tags: android, kotlin, appicon

I have successfully changed the app icon dynamically using below

```kotlin
    manager.setComponentEnabledSetting( 
            ComponentName(this@MainActivity2, "com.appicon.ui.MainActivity"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP 
        ) // enable new icon 

    manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            ComponentName(this@MainActivity2, "com.appicon.MainActivityAlias"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )
```

But the app icon is not updating in App Info setting screen. In app info setting is showing the old app icon. Also newly changed app icon is not reflecting in recent history view.

Is this an expected behavior?

I am expecting the newly changed icon to be reflected in App Info setting screen and in recent history view screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no official method to change the app icon dynamically

Comment: Most of the app icons from what I have seen publishing apps to play store is that Google does all the the changes to the icon on app settings in phone